# JavaFX: Error message with ChangeListener

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, changelistener

While I was coding, I added the following piece of code:

```
nameComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<NameVO>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends NameVO> observable,
                NameVO oldValue, NameVO newValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And the Eclipse is showing me Red line under `addListener` and moving mouse over that I could see the following message:

`The method addListener(ChangeListener<? super capture#6-of ?>) in the type ObservableValue<capture#6-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (new ChangeListener<NameVO>(){})`

Why would this be because of?

[Note: I have done similar thing for remaining ComboBoxes, but I am getting no such message over there]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution!

For all other ComboBoxes, the declaration involved the respective value object.

For example:

```
@FXML //  fx:id="projectComboBox"
private ComboBox<ProjectVO> projectComboBox; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
```

But, `nameComboBox` was simple declared as:

```
@FXML //  fx:id="nameComboBox"
private ComboBox<?> nameComboBox; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
```

Added `NameVO` at the place of `?` and got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be expecting `ObservableValue<NameVO>` as opposed to `ObservableValue<? extends NameVO>`.

To start off, look at how you are explicitly stating the type argument for your `ChangeListener`:

`new ChangeListener<NameVO>{ .... }`

You are explicitly stating that it is `NameVO` but when you actually go to implement the method, you are changing it to `? extends NameVO`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried that. It gives me another error message, if I try to do so: `The method changed(ObservableValue<NameVO>, NameVO, NameVO) of type new ChangeListener<NameVO>(){} must override or implement a supertype method`

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple, just add the below to your import

```
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
```

Comment: No - why? how would that help?